# Adding annotation feature class to mxd with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, feature-layer, annotation

Annotation feature classes in personal geodatabases need to be added to mxds. The annotation is not already in the mxd. I tried [Make Feature Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000) and add layer through arcpy.mapping and it did not work. Esri states that complex features such as annotation are not supported.

Do I have to open 88 mxds and drag in the annotation feature classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you tried and researched but I just ran the test below using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop and the annotation feature class from a personal geodatabase (*.mdb) was added to my map using ArcPy.

```
import arcpy

# C:\temp\test.mxd is a blank map
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\temp\test.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"C:\temp\test.mdb\AnnoFC","annoFL")
annoLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("annoFL")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,annoLayer)
mxd.save()
```

To give credit where it's due my quick research uncovered the basis of the above coding pattern in a [GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/100762).

Comment: Huh. How about that. I had the exact same problem where it was adding the annotion as a polygon fc. Works just fine in 10.0. Awesome, thanks!